# Iris mechanism nomenclature - need help to enable better search results

Tags: mechanical-engineering, nomenclature, research

I'm researching iris mechanisms with the goal of building a functioning, weather-sealed door. I am learning much as I go along, but am faced with a challenge in nomenclature (I am not an engineer).

I am using Google to search for non-overlapping iris mechanism designs that have the smallest possible distance from the outer edge of the opening to the outer edge of the 'housing' (the word that naturally comes to me to describe that part of the device) - but I am stumped about how to narrow down my search results.

Using the terms "small housing", "narrow housing", "smallest perimeter" etc are not proving to be useful when searching. No meaningful changes in the search results (and there are a gazillion results - I didn't know this mechanism was so popular in the DIY home-cnc world). "Enclosure" and "concealment" do not seem to impact the results much either.

Can anyone advise me on ***what terms I should use that will enable me to narrow my results***? <--- THAT is the question being asked.

Comment: This may be relevant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3TJU2JgTUSU

Comment: Are you planning to use the iris as a window in your door, or as the door itself?

Comment: Have seen that video already, but thanks - it's a nice design. Plan is to build an iris door, not a door with an iris window. So any input regarding the question - nomenclature for the area of these mechanisms outside the opening area?

Answer (score 0):

I have found iris diaphragm [patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US5576792) and there are other patents cited, you can find shape of the blade in one of them. Modifying shape of the blade you can get full closure. I do not think that size is relevant. Though waterseal might mean hydrostatic pressure thus increased moment and stresses so size might be important. There are also questions of intelectual property. Because your design would be based on someone's patent in this case.

Second source that might be relevant was [sliding iris mechanism](https://www.google.hr/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www3.imperial.ac.uk/pls/portallive/docs/1/375907.PDF&ved=0ahUKEwjikZzn6-TXAhUGnRQKHaxCAh4QFgiAATAV&usg=AOvVaw3vm0s86JvdqQPUepIEKaeF).

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the design, and I already understand how to lay out and cut the vanes to get full closure. As to I. P. concerns, LOL! Really? Not a concern. So do you have any input regarding the question posed about nomenclature for the outer non-opening part of the mechanism?

Comment: And weather-sealed does not mean 'hydrostatic pressure'. It just means the edges of the vanes need to interlock and have a compressible gasket and the mechanism only needs to supply enough pressure on the gasket to attain a weatherseal. I'm a professional joiner, sealing a door of any sort is basic stuff.

Comment: @Nixt I was thinking about immersing object in water but was wrong so ok, not pressure. Even simpler. If you browse cited patents you will find other parts of Iris mechanism.

Comment: You could use eg Solidworks and model your door in 3d and simulate whole mechanism, there are some done in videos on youtube. If you have mech. engineering faculty close by you can check library for literature about mechanisms, or maybe pfotography school or multimedia faculty about building lenses and lense shutters.

Comment: Try looking for camera shutter mechanism smth like http://www.earlyphotography.co.uk/site/shutterm.html or this http://www.piercevaubel.com/cam/acc/shb&ldiaphagmtransitional587.htm